# HTML5 Input datetime-local default value of today and current time using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetimepicker

I want to set the default value of datetime-local to current date and time(time should contain only Hours and minutes like '2014-01-02T11:42'.) using angularJs.

**EDIT**:
following is my html code

```
 <center><input type="datetime-local" name="start date"  ng-model="endDate" id="from_date"></center>
```

angularJs code

```
 $scope.endtDate=new Date(new Date().getTime()).toLocaleString();
```

by this method I am able to set the current date and time but it also inclodes seconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed the code and solved my problem

```
$scope.endDateTime=new Date();
var h = $scope.endDateTime.getHours();
var m = $scope.endDateTime.getMinutes();
$scope.endDateTime.setHours(h,m,0,0);
```

this will only set hours and minutes.
cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use date filter for displaying date..

Look at the following link..

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ref_date

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

I hope this will help

Comment: Actually I am using datetime-local input type in that I need to set the current date and time..by the date filter I am not able to set.

Comment: what are you getting in front-end...a big number..?

Comment: Could you please provide your plunkr

Comment: I never used plunkr..so I cant provide you but I have given some code above..please help me out

Comment: First change your ng-model name...it should be "endtDate"

Answer (score 0):

Use angular filter put the date variable instead of the numbers.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('dateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
});
</script>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HXDsILCtyliiamxdABZn?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="dateCtrl">

   <span>{{today | date:"MM/dd/yyyy'T' h:mm"}}</span><br>
</body>
```

Comment: I need date time picker that is why I have used input tag type datetime-local

Comment: Yeah you can now use DOM Manipulation to format the date.

Comment: Wait i will provide you the solution.

Comment: on browser it is not showing second but on mobile it is showing seconds. I don't know what is happening.
please modify ur plunkr according tho my requirement